# Cannot find whether the browser is opened or the webdriver instance is running or not in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two test cases need to be executed.

1. Login as admin
2. Do some action

I'm using TestNG and Cucumber BDD for executing the test cases. Now I execute the project as TestNG and from testng.xml it will run the two test cases one by one. First it will login and then do the action.

I'm using Page Factory method for page objects.

So, when I execute my project, the login test case is executed but it cannot find the element in that logged in screen/page, because it cannot find whether the browser is open or the webdriver instance is running.

This is my testng.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Super admin">
<test name="Login as Admin">
<classes>
  <class name="adminlogin"/>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="admin disable">
<classes>
  <class name="admindisable"/>
</classes>
```

For adminlogin I have separate class and for admindisable I've separate class. So, when the admindisable is executed it cannot find the element on the page.

This is my login class code:

```
 public class adminLoginTest {

  /**
 * Initialize the webdriver.
 */
  private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

/**
 * Initialize
 */
private adminloginpage adminLoginDetails;

@When("login super admin")
public final void adminLogin(List<adminlogindetails> loginInfo) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("site url");
    adminLoginDetails = new adminloginpage(driver);
    adminlogindetails loginInformation = loginInfo.get(0);
        adminLoginDetails.getUserName().sendKeys(loginInformation.getUserName());
    adminLoginDetails.getPassword().sendKeys(loginInformation.getPassword());
    adminLoginDetails.getLoginBtn().click();
}

 }
```

After this the admin is logged in.

Do some action code:

```
@When("Login for disable")
  public void disableDeleteEditUserId(List<admindisabledeleteeditnfpadminuseriddetail> nfpDetails) {

 nfpObjects = new admindisabledeleteeditnfpadminuseridpage(driver);
admindisabledeleteeditnfpadminuseriddetail nfpDetailInfo = nfpDetails.get(0);

nfpObjects.getNfpMenuLink().click();
nfpObjects.getNfpOrgLink().click();
nfpObjects.getAllTablink().click();
nfpObjects.getSearchBox().sendKeys(nfpDetailInfo.getSearchBox());
nfpObjects.getSearchButton().click();

}
```

In the do some action code, I don't know how to instantiate the webdriver or how to check the condition that the webdriver is already running? Because the problem is, it cannot find the link 'getNfpMenuLink' in the already logged in browser.

This is my page objects code:

```
/**
* Initialize web driver.
*/
 private WebDriver driver;

/**
* Find the nfpMenuLink.
*/
  @FindBy(xpath = "html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")
 private WebElement nfpMenuLink;

 /**
 * @return nfpMenuLink.
 */
   public WebElement getNfpMenuLink() {
     return nfpMenuLink;
   }

   /**
    * @param nfpMenuLink the nfpMenuLink.
  */
  public void setNfpMenuLink(WebElement nfpMenuLink) {
  this.nfpMenuLink = nfpMenuLink;
  }

 /**
 * @param driver the driver.
 */
  public Superadmindisabledeleteeditnfpadminuseridpage(WebDriver driver) {

 this.driver = driver;
 PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error you get? how do you know its looking for webdriver instance? can you share how have you created page objects. In your code above you are initiating `nfpObjects` but using `Objects` , i wonder if that is the issue.

Comment: This is the error I received:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.click(Unknown Source)
 at mypackagename(classname.java:39)
 at ✽.When My scenario name(src/test/resources/features/featurefilename.feature:5)`.
I have added my page object code for your reference in my question.
Please ignore the `nfpObjects` and `Objects` that is typo error.

Comment: I'd say try using css selector on the same element instead of xpath in page obejcts. is it a page that you can share here?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I can't share the page. Actually with this xpath itself it was working fine with another setup. I think the problem is because of the webdriver instance issue or the script is not finding the existing opened browser window.

Comment: in that case, use `String Window = driver.getWindowHandle();` to get handle of the window during initial stages of your test then use this `driver.switchTo().window(Window);` to switch to your window. Thereafter, you can also use `((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");` to bring your window to focus and then put your  `element` and `click` code. It should work.

Comment: I tried your code.. but it didn't work.. also instead of finding the element through Page Factoring I used `driver.findElement(By.xpath)` but that also failed.

`String Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.switchTo().window(Window);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();`
The error shown is a NullPointerException.